# table numbers are wrong for double column table

Tags: floats, positioning, numbering, two-column, starred-version

My:

```
\begin{table*}[t]
   \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
     \begin{tabular}
      \end{tabular}
      \CaptionType{table}
      \caption{...}
      \label{tab:res2}
    \end{minipage}
    \\
    %another "table" in a minipage
 \end{table}
```

Comes after a

```
\begin{table}[t]
...
\caption{..}
\label{tab:res1}
\end{table}
```

in my .dvi file but in the source it comes before. This has the effect generating wrong table numbers. How can I fix this? Either make sure that the table appears in the same order in the dvi file as in the tex file or even better to make sure that the table numbers are assigned according to the order in the dvi file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, it's a bug left in for compatibility reasons, load

```
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
```